# Need help retrieving site column names using REST service call in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, rest, odata

I need to retrieve content types and accompanying site column names and fields. Does anyone know how to construct the REST notation to accomplish this?

I have tried variations of:
/lists/sitecontents
/web/contenttypes/?('fields')
/web/group
web/fieldtypekind
/web/availablefields
_api/Web/lists?$select=fields

but I am stumped.[image: SHarePoint Designer showing fields I need to retrieve]

Comment: try _api/web/lists('8025CCE1-25C1-4B3F-B1FC-41D121983335')/contenttypes

Comment: _api/web/lists('8025CCE1-25C1-4B3F-B1FC-41D121983335')/fields

Answer (score 4):

The following SharePoint REST query could be used to retrieve content type names and accompanying field names:

```
/_api/web/contenttypes?$select=Name,Fields/InternalName&$expand=Fields/InternalName
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, That did it. There are some fields that I see in SharePoint Designer that the command did not pull. Wonder why. However this is a great start. Many thanks.